# What "bhog" could we give to various Deities if we dont want to give sweets always

Tags: food, prasad

We want to reduce our sugar intake, so we are looking for alternative food items that various Gods like.
For Lakshmi and Narayan atleast to begin with.
Hoping someone here could help with some information in this matter, with appropriate sources.